# Taglib artist string error System.String[]

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

have anyone are a idea why im getting here a Error (I've already tried it with this String `f.Tag.Performers.ToString();`)

> > but then the label shows System.String[]

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(paths[Playlist.SelectedIndex]);
ArtistLabel.Text = f.Tag.Performers; //f.Tag.Performers are the Error
if (f.Tag.Performers == null)
     ArtistLabel.Text = "unbekannt";
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this is an array of strings:

```
f.Tag.Performers
```

And this is clearly a string:

```
ArtistLabel.Text
```

Basically, a basket of apples is not an apple.  How do you want the array of strings to display?  For example, you might join them separated by commas:

```
ArtistLabel.Text = string.Join(", ", f.Tag.Performers);
```

There are a variety of approaches you can take to format your output.  The point is that the system doesn't do it for you because it doesn't know what format you want.  You can join the array, loop over it and append to the output, bind a set of controls to it, etc.

Comment: +1 i understood it, Arrays are lots of information and a string is just one information. Thanks this will help me. :)

Comment: Thanks for analogy *Basically, a basket of apples is not an apple.* +1 for it

Answer (score 0):

As error says `f.Tag.Performers` is of type `string[]`. Either override `.ToString()` function or use `string.Join()` function like

```
 ArtistLabel.Text = string.Join(" ", f.Tag.Performers);
```